# IntelliJ sort enum members

Tags: sorting, intellij-idea, enums, alphabetical

Is there any way to sort the member variables of an enum alphabetically in IntelliJ? I've been trying a bunch of different settings in the arrangement section but didn't have success. Could anyone maybe help me?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on an enum constant and invoke the `sort content` intention. This will sort the enum constants in alphabetical order. The intention will only appear if the constants are not alphabetically sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Wasn't able to find the same action for AndroidStuido, instead, I used Menu -> Edit -> Sort Lines

Good thing is that it can be used for anything :)

[image]